# Inexplicable delays when setting TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, adodb

One of my colleagues was on a customer site where they were complaining about occasional sluggish behaviour of our application.

He ran a SQL Profiler on their SQL Server database (2008 R2)

Looking at its output he claims that there were occasional significant delays on some SQL statements, but bizarrely the statement he claims would often show a delay was:

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement. JUST the above.

How is it possible that it could take 12 to 14 seconds for it to simply process that instruction?

The calling code was written in Visual Studio.NET (VB.NET) using ADODB

Comment: How did your colleague trace it to that line? SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL is like a preprocessor directive and would have no runtime delay. It sounds more like a red- hearing of sorts. I bet you are running into an optimization anomaly in stored procedure execution like "Parameter Sniffing". At least you can rule that out by configuring the OPTIMIZE FOR and WITH RECOMPILE directives.

Comment: Hello lrb, can you add a little explanation regarding the term "Parameter Sniffing" and how I should use the "OPTIMIZE FOR" and "WITH RECOMPILE" directives? And what should I be using those against?

Comment: Hello lrb,

You were quite right - it was a red herring. I have now been able to see the actual trace itself, and while there were a few of those statements in there alright, there were also others. What was much more interesting was that they were all clustered around a 4 minute interval. We looked for statements that had taken more than 10 seconds to execute. The first of these statements was logged at 15:26, the last one at 15:30

So it looks like something else was happening on that server in that period.